# ElasticSearch comma inside the number

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to remove commas inside numbers take for instance "Warhammer 40,000: Dawn of War III"

I want it to match if u search for "40000".

But currently my tokenizer gives me:

```
{
"tokens": [
{
"token": "warhammer",
"start_offset": 0,
"end_offset": 9,
"type": "word",
"position": 0
},
{
"token": "warhammer 40",
"start_offset": 0,
"end_offset": 12,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 0
},
{
"token": "40",
"start_offset": 10,
"end_offset": 12,
"type": "word",
"position": 1
},
{
"token": "000:",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 17,
"type": "word",
"position": 102
},
{
"token": "000: 000",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 16,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 102
},
{
"token": "000: 000 dawn",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 22,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 102
},
{
"token": "000: 000 dawn of",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 25,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 102
},
{
"token": "000: 000 dawn of war",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 29,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 102
},
{
"token": "000: 000 dawn of war 3",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 33,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 102
},
{
"token": "000",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 16,
"type": "word",
"position": 103
},
{
"token": "000 dawn",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 22,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 103
},
{
"token": "000 dawn of",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 25,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 103
},
{
"token": "000 dawn of war",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 29,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 103
},
{
"token": "000 dawn of war 3",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 33,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 103
},
{
"token": "dawn",
"start_offset": 18,
"end_offset": 22,
"type": "word",
"position": 104
},
{
"token": "dawn of",
"start_offset": 18,
"end_offset": 25,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 104
},
{
"token": "dawn of war",
"start_offset": 18,
"end_offset": 29,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 104
},
{
"token": "dawn of war 3",
"start_offset": 18,
"end_offset": 33,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 104
},
{
"token": "of war",
"start_offset": 23,
"end_offset": 29,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 105
},
{
"token": "of war 3",
"start_offset": 23,
"end_offset": 33,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 105
},
{
"token": "war",
"start_offset": 26,
"end_offset": 29,
"type": "word",
"position": 106
},
{
"token": "war 3",
"start_offset": 26,
"end_offset": 33,
"type": "shingle",
"position": 106
},
{
"token": "3",
"start_offset": 30,
"end_offset": 33,
"type": "SYNONYM",
"position": 107
}
]
}
```

The main issue here is that "40" and "000" is different tokens. I think it's best to treat them as a single token "40000" is there a token filter that can merge the two?

**EDIT:** 
Ohhhh!
I tried:

```
      "analyzer": {
    "default": {
      "tokenizer": "keyword"
    }}
```

The result of:
http://localhost:9200/i/_analyze?text=Warhammer%2040,000:%20Dawn%20of%20War%20III
Gave me:

```
    {
"tokens": [
{
"token": "Warhammer 40",
"start_offset": 0,
"end_offset": 12,
"type": "word",
"position": 0
},
{
"token": "000: Dawn of War III",
"start_offset": 13,
"end_offset": 33,
"type": "word",
"position": 101
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge numbers with decimal points using a character filter. In the following snippet the character filter called "decimal_mark_filter" will remove any comma that appears in-between numbers before tokenization takes place.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "decimal_mark_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "decimal_mark_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\d+),(?=\\d)",
          "replacement": "$1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The analyzer gives the following tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Warhammer",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "40000",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "Dawn",
      "start_offset": 18,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "of",
      "start_offset": 23,
      "end_offset": 25,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "War",
      "start_offset": 26,
      "end_offset": 29,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "III",
      "start_offset": 30,
      "end_offset": 33,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

This is just a modification of an example on [the official Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html#_example_configuration_15)